# Use previously printed text in a command

Tags: shell, zsh

Often I will have a terminal command that outputs some suggested commands to run next, or a file path amongst multi-line text output.

I want to be able to re-use the file path or the command.

E.g.

```
$ nativefier --name "Asana Personal" "https://app.asana.com"
Packaging app for platform darwin x64 using electron v1.6.6
App built to /Users/Vaughan/Asana Personal-darwin-x64


$ cd /Users<press-tab>/Vaughan/Asana Personal-darwin-x64


$ brew info postgres
...
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.0) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/upgrading.html

To migrate existing data from a previous minor version (9.0-9.5) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html

  You will need your previous PostgreSQL installation from brew to perform `pg_upgrade`.
  Do not run `brew cleanup postgresql` until you have performed the migration.

To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start


$ pg ctl<press-tab>-D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

Comment: Is that only on terminal or are you asking aswell on a GUI terminal? With a GUI terminal usually you can mark the command/path you want and use the middle mouse key to paste it (no need to manually copy it). If you are talking about plain TTY I think you're out of luck unless you are building a script in which you can use `sed` or `cut` or any other stream editor to filter for what you want and use that onwards.

Comment: @Ziazis I am looking for a solution without using mouse/trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

This would basically mean to log you whole terminal sessions to capture the info you want.

For doing that, you could use the program `script` (e.g. put `script /tmp/myuseronlyreadablefile` into your `.zshrc`, or enhance your prompt to use `script` on this one line of input on the same log file again and again, parsing it immediatly after that), and you would then parse the generated log file (filter output for all paths) for a widget you set for  [zsh auto completion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html).

I am not sure which drawbacks the usage of 'script' may have and how much effort this will mean to you compared to the good old '*mark any text with the mouse and simply insert it immediatly with a click on my mouse wheel*' functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal multiplexers such as `tmux` and `screen` support copy and paste from the session, but if you wanted to do this without one, or automatically, you could use `tee` to send the output to a temp file, and use `cut`, `sed` and/or `grep` to build (and then run) said command.

However, since you appear to be using OSX, you can simply highlight text, and press ⌘C to copy, and ⌘V to paste. (Unless you are `ssh`'d in)